# How does the compiler know where control should return to after a function call?

Tags: c++

Consider the following functions:

```
int main()
{
    //statement(s);
    func1();
    //statement(s);
}

void func1()
{
    //statement(s);
    func2();
    //statement(s);
}

void func2()
{
    //statement(s);
}
```

How does the compiler know where to return to after the `func2` has performed all its operations? I know the control transfers to function `func1` (and exactly which statement), but *how* does *the compiler* knows it? What tells the compiler where to return to?

Comment: The compiler (normally) doesn't. Look up how the call stack works, and then look up x86 calling conventions for the details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is typically implemented using a [*call stack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack):

- When control is being transfered to a function, the address to return to is pushed onto the stack.
- When the function finishes, the address is popped off the stack and used to transfer control back to the callee.

The details are typically mandated by the hardware architecture for which the code is being compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the compiler doesn't run the code, but the machine does, and when it calls a new function, it stores the address of the *next* instruction to be executed after the function currently being called on the stack, so that when the function returns it can pop it off back in to the Instruction Pointer (IP) and resume from there.

I've simplified things a bit for the sake of explanation.

Comment: Thanks I get the picture now. :D

Answer (score 2):

When a function is called, the correct return address in the calling function is placed somewhere, usually the stack though the standard does not mandate that, that is used for precisely the purpose of storing the return address.

It is the compiler's duty to ensure that its calling conventions are such that unless something goes wrong (for example, a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)), then the called function knows how to return to the calling function.

Comment: The Standard mandates a stack.  It doesn't specify a particular implementation, however, so compilers are free to use the CPU stack-handling instructions or not.

Comment: The C++ standard does mandate a stack?  Hmmm...interesting; the C standard does not.

Comment: @BenVoigt Care to elaborate how it mandates a stack? I know it requires LIFO behavior for construction and deconstruction of objects, but I don't see a stack as a requirement for this, just as a natural fit.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am sure you are write (as you seem to be write in most of our discussions) but can you elaborate where in the standard?

Comment: The sections on exception handling and `std::terminate` discuss unwinding of the call stack, in both notes and normative rules.  Of course the as-if rule applies -- it may be possible to implement the "call stack" semantics without using a stack.  And certainly a compiler-managed stack data structure is a viable alternative to `PUSH` and `POP` instructions (might be advantageous for coroutines, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The runtime makes use of some thing called as a 'call stack' which basically holds the address of the next statement to call after the function being called is returned. So when a function call is made and before the control jumps to the new instruction address, the next instruction address in the calling function is pushed on to the stack. And this process is repeated for every subsequent call to any function. Now why only a stack? because it's necessary to get back to the point where it left off - which is basically a 'last in first out' behavior and stack is the data structure that does that. You can actually look at this call stack when you are debugging a program in Visual Studio - there's a separate window called 'Call Stack' which shows the entries of the addresses placed in the call stack.